# sublime text 3 minimap click and drag

Tags: sublimetext3

In sublime text 2, I can click on the minimap and drag. 
in st3, it only works only when click on the 'current' view port.
I've added

```
"minimap_scroll_to_clicked_text": true
```

into settings-user;
How can I make it click and drag at any position? Thanks :P;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the last build 3059 (December 17th, 2013), I see a click and drag when I set:

```
"minimap_scroll_to_clicked_text": false,
```

[image: http://shrekuu.ueuo.com/images/sublime_minimap_feature1.png]

If I click anywhere in the green zone (with ST3 build 3059), the text will move to be in sync with that new zone.

Comment: Thanks. I see. Maybe I ask for too much. LOL. I wish they add a function that when press down left button and drag at any point on the minimap. I don't know whether I've expressed it clearly.

Comment: @Shrek That does work: when I left click on the minimap and drag on it, the all text moves.

Comment: I mean at any point, not only the current view. Currently when you click on not the current view part, it slides there. You have to click on the current view part to drag. Thanks.

Comment: @Shrek "at any point" where: I only have one current view at a time, and the minimap is kept in sync with that text. But I have to click on the minimap. Did you mean "click anywhere in the text, outside the minimap"?

Comment: Thanks :) I do ask for too much. I meant directly drag from the green area. Press down the left button and drag immediately. It does not have this feature. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @Shrek It does, it seems: I press down the left button anywhere in the green area and I see the main text *immediately* switch to it.

Comment: Shrek is right, he is saying that something should be done for a click+drag gesture performed where the click starts outside the "current" range. Basically in order to do drag u have to click, release, click again to drag. Which 99.95% of users (myself and Mr. Shrek here excluded) are satisfied with.

Comment: @StevenLu Please read the answer carefully. In order to make this work you have to set `"minimap_scroll_to_clicked_text"` to **`false`**, not to `true` like in the question. I checked it in the latest build (3083) on Windows and it still works. Yes, it isn't the default setting, but it is still possible to set it in Sublime Text 3. Otherwise it would be a regression.

Comment: I am well aware of the distinction, I was one of the people who posted on the original Sublime Forum thread that prompted Sublime's author to make two behavioral modes for click handling in the minimap. If you set `"minimap_scroll_to_clicked_text": false,` it will indeed respond to a click starting outside, however it directly warps you to that position of the file and not necessarily to what that spot on the minimap actually represents. This difference is subtle but is very important for large files. [here is the discussion](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3414)